# A strange issue with open programs

Tags: xubuntu

Recently my speakers stopped working. I was able to work it out with this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

While I was happy to have sound back, it came with a larger problem. The 'windows' around open programs aren't there. I don't know if there's a term for it, but the border around things with the close button and everything just isn't there. 
Some things (like the internet) I'm simply unable to close, nor can I access any other programs without logging out completely. I'm using a xubuntu desktop, and I don't have the issues with the ubuntu desktop. I know I could just use that, but I really just can't stand it.

I also seem to be unable to right click anything.

Does anyone please have a solution?

Comment: Your window decorator is malfunctioning.  Use replace or use mainline.

Answer (score 0):

as soon as you start a new session, 
open a terminal window, and type: /usr/bin/xfwm4 --replace
tell me if it fixes your problem.

(if ok, one next step would be to add this command in automatic start command)